# Using Jackson with object mapper to ignore some fields in a deserialization to JSON in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

Assume I have a class like this

```
class A{
@JsonProperty
private String f1;
@JsonProperty
private String f2;
}
```

I know, that using jackson annotations I can ignore null fields:

```
class A{
 @JsonProperty
 private String f1;
 @JsonProperty
 @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
 private String f2;
}
```

But this annotation doesn't work if I'm ussing an object mapper like this:

```
A obj = new A();
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(writer, obj);
```

I know that I can control the global with

```
mapper = apper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

But, Is it possible to do the same thing using the object mapper?

Comment: Read about @JsonIgnore

Comment: Look at the configure methods in ObjectMapper

Comment: @Madhan I tried the JsonIgnore ... but I don't know why when using the ObjectMapper, doesn't work.

Comment: What is the error you are getting.Or What do you want to achieve. Explain that in your question. And How did you used the JSONIgnore